# MS Access TextBox events won't fire

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to filter my listbox `lstOutput`on the fly as the user types into my textbox `txtInput` however none of the key events on my textbox fire until I click my listbox and then go back to my textbox.

Here is the code I am using

```
Private Sub txtInput_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT Patient.PatientID, Patient.FName, Patient.LName " & _
    "FROM Patient " & _
    "WHERE (((Patient.FName)=[Forms]![New Session]![txtInput]) OR ((Patient.LName)=[Forms]![New Session]![txtInput])) " & _
    "ORDER BY Patient.[FName], Patient.[LName];"

Me.lstResults.RowSource = strSQL
Me.lstResults.Requery
End Sub
```

I have tried the `KeyUp`, `KeyDown`, `Dirty`, `Change` events as well but to avail. The only one that works is the `AfterUpdate` event but I won't the results to filter as the user types and not after pressing enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnChange is the event you want to use, this event triggers whenever you make a change to the TEXT in the textbox.
Now the default property of a textbox is VALUE.
As you type the .TEXT of the textbox is changed, when you hit enter/tab the .VALUE is changed. You need to reference to the .TEXT like:

```
[Forms]![New Session]![txtInput].Text
```

This should hopefully get you started

Comment: Ok now I feel just silly. This worked perfectly. One thing though, would it better to do what I am doing via VBA or use a query that I have already created? Creating a query in design mode is easier for me since I can use expression builder and drag and drop.

Comment: @Chris If designing the query in design mode is easier for you I think there's no need to change something you're comfortable with :) (I assume you meant your "strSQL")